# Run Native SQL Command in Azure Scheduler

Tags: javascript, azure

I have been trying to achieve this myself for 3 days now and combined with my knowledge and searching have come up blank! Just edited and change the question to be a bit more "generic" but lead me to a solution.

Using the azure mobile services scheduler, JavaScript, I want to increment a value for each record in a table. Basically run "turns++" on the table, up to a maximum of a certain amount.

Is there a way to run a native SQL command in the azure scheduler?

**For Example:** Connect to the database and run "SELECT * FROM tableName" as this will let me run the increment that I need.

*Alternatively* is there a way, which I'm assuming more complicated, to run *"for each"* on records from the table and then update them with a field incremented?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Advice from MSDN Evangelist is that you cant do this in Azure Scheduler as it has only 3 action verbs - HTTP, HTTPS and Queue.
https://twitter.com/plankytronixx/status/516899252749225985

The solution is to use a free azure website and their new feature "web jobs". I did this with PHP but web jobs supports more languages.

```
$options = array("Database" => "database name", 

                           "UID" => "userid",

                           "PWD" => "password",

                           "MultipleActiveResultSets" => false);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($hostname, $options)or die ("Cannot connect to host");


sqlsrv_query($conn, "UPDATE schema.tablename SET turns = turns+1 WHERE turns < 10;")or die (print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
```

More about Azure web jobs here http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/

Answer (score 1):

You **CAN** do this in Azure Scheduler! It provides a special [mssql object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj554212.aspx) which is initialized with connection to the current Database associated with the Azure Mobile Service. And it is extremely easy to use:

```
function sql() {

    mssql.query('select top 3 * from TestTable', {
      success: function(results) {
         console.log(results);
         for (var testObj in results) {
           console.log('id: ' + results[testObj].id + 'name : ' + results[testObj].fname);
        }
      },
      error: function(err) {
                console.log("error is: " + err);
      }
   });
}
```

(Note that here 'sql' is just the name of my Scheduler Job) The only trick is, that if you want to access tables that **are not part** of the Standard Mobile Services API tables, you will have to explicitly grant read/write access to those tables following [this nice guide](http://www.johankarlsson.net/2013/04/accessing-non-mobile-services-tables-in.html).

The Result of execution of the above script is this:

[image: Azure Scheduler results]

Looping through the records you can do much more than just dumping to the log - i.e. execute other queries, etc. You can read the full documentation of the [mssql object here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj554212.aspx).

Comment: Interesting thanks for that. Turns out the advice direct from and MSDN evangelist was wrong! However the answer I provided isn't wrong as it still works!

Comment: I will not agree that your answer is correct! The question is about Azure Scheduler, and you provide answer about using Azure Web Job. Scheduler and WebJob are absolutely different services. In your answer you just pretend that Scheduler does not support direct work with SQL Server. You even mention an advice from MSDN without a link to that source.

Comment: The question was how to run a SQL command on a schedule on an azure database in azure, and this is answered by doing it. I will happily update my answer with a source. I have never said at any point your answer is wrong, merely that they both achieve the same goal. In fact Web Jobs seem better as there is a higher limit on the number for free, whereas the scheduler is just 1 job!

Comment: Dude, your question, its title and its content is all about Azure Mobile Services Scheduler!! Your question is not generic about how to run something on specific interval. Your question is about how to perform operation XXXX on Azure Mobile Services Scheduler. But I will stop this conversation here.